# Change of D.O.B in Indian Passport

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, paperwork

Can I change my Date of Birth ( a new one) in Passport at the time of Renewal? Is it possible? If yes then how to do that??

Comment: As people have only one date of birth,  you might need to proof the earlier one as faulty and you did not bother have it corrected. I am not familiar with the laws and rules in India, but where I live it would be a mayor pain.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an [FAQ](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqMiscellaneous) on errors in a passport:

> Passport with incorrect details printed
>   Q9:  Incorrect details have
>   been printed on my passport. What should I do?
>   A:  If you find any
>   mistake/error in the particulars printed in the passport booklet and
>   the application form you submitted, please return the passport for
>   necessary rectification. Any additional fees required to be paid would
>   depend on the merits of the case to be decided by the Assistant
>   Passport Officer (APO)/RPO. If there is a misrepresentation of facts,
>   then penalty could also be imposed. However, applicants are requested
>   to apply online with the view to ensure that the passports are
>   delivered without any typographical errors since applicants have
>   themselves fed the data.

Now what that means in real-life, I don't know.

Comment: +1,  can you remove those questions in the last paragraph? The FAQ citation you provided fully answers the OP's question.

Comment: @GayotFow Done!